# How to do a proxychains of 2 proxy using redsocks?

Tags: proxy

Redsocks doesnt allow to do proxy chaining. I need to forward all the https and http request coming from the outside to a chain of 2 proxy. Is there transparent proxy that allow proxy-chaining ?